# Como ler os dados de um aquivo.xml e exibir em um textbox

Tags: c#, xml

Tenho uma aplicação que gera um arquivo XML, mas não estou conseguindo ler o arquivo XML e inserir no TextBox.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <parametros>
  <banco>rango</banco>
  <caminho>C:\</caminho>
 </parametros>
```

preciso que a aplicação leia este xml e "importe" a informação pra um textbox.

Comment: Bom, aí não está tentando mandar para um `TextBox`, você já tentou colocar nele? Há algum problema para ler o XML? Qual? O seu código está fazendo só isto. Talvez você tenha duas dificuldades separadas.

Comment: Desculpa, é porque tem um textbox e um combobox mas os dois pegam o texto e não o indice.

Comment: Poderia colocar o xml e indicar mais detalhes para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Pergunta editada @DiegoSantos

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues O ideal que você também deixasse a codificação anterior em C#. Verifica se é isso mesmo que você quer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta é isto:`

```
 XmlTextReader x = new XmlTextReader(@".\\SS-BACKUP.xml");

            while (x.Read())
            {
                if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "banco")
                    cb_Banco.Text = (x.ReadString());
                if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "caminho")
                    tb_Caminho.Text = (x.ReadString());
                if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "servidor")
                    tb_Servidor.Text = (x.ReadString());
                if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "usuario")
                    tb_Usuario.Text = (x.ReadString());
                if (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && x.Name == "senha")
                    tb_Senha.Text = (x.ReadString());
            }

            x.Close();
            return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando como base o que você tinha, adicionado atribui um + textBox que vai funcionar como um append.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\diego-santos\\Desktop\\teste.xml");

while (reader.Read())
{
  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
  {
      tb_Caminho.Text += reader.Value;
  }
}
```

o resultado = rangoC:\